# Stay in active accordion when returning back to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

i have a first page with accordion of 4 blocs which contains links, The accordion works good except when i click a link and return back, the accordions are closed..What i want is to keep clicked/current one active  when clicking back.
Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(".clsBlock > div").on("click", function() {
         if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
             $(this).removeClass("active");
             $(this).siblings('.clsBlockContent').slideUp(200);
             $(this).siblings('.clsBlockHeaderReduce').slideUp(200);
             $(this).find('.clsBlockHeaderReduce').removeClass('clsBlockHeaderReduceHoriz');
         } else {
             $(".clsBlock > div").removeClass("active");
             $('.clsBlockContent').slideUp(200);
             $(".clsBlock > div").find('.clsBlockHeaderReduce').removeClass('clsBlockHeaderReduceHoriz');
             $(this).addClass("active");
             $(this).siblings('.clsBlockContent').slideDown(200);
             $(this).find('.clsBlockHeaderReduce').addClass('clsBlockHeaderReduceHoriz');
         }
    });
});
```

Thank you,

Comment: You will have to store that data that will persist even after URL changes. You can either store it as a cookie (dated method), in localStorage (yay for client-side storage!), or you can even invoke hash changes when opening different tabs (hash changes are automatically stored in browser history). There are various plugins out there that provide tab functionality + state preservation, so perhaps it's really not needed to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: @Terry thank's ...i did some research ..can't figure out how to do it. I found something like this :
`var hash = $(this).attr('div');
document.title = 'The hash is ' + (hash.replace('#', '') || 'blank') + '.';
location.hash = hash;`
But don"t know how to use it in my code ..still trying